Using Python to obtain monthly general ledger for AWS China region
Use the following Python code to obtain the monthly total bill for AWS China. After the code is executed, some information is obtained. However, when the obtained data is compared with the final bill result on the console, it is found that the bill number obtained by using the Python code is inconsistent with the total bill number displayed on the console. How should this be solved? Is the parameter of the above Python code wrong? For example, the total bill displayed on the console is 649.53, but the total bill obtained by Python is 646.95
import boto3
import ast

time_start = '2024-06-01'
time_end = '2024-07-01'
billing_results = []


def get_aws_bill_summary(access_key_id, access_key_num):

    # user security key
    access_key_id = access_key_id
    access_key_num = access_key_num

    # get account id
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts',
                              aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
                              aws_secret_access_key=access_key_num,
                              region_name='cn-northwest-1'
                              )
    response = sts_client.get_caller_identity()
    account_id = response['Account']
    # print(account_id)

    # get billing cost total
    client = boto3.client('ce',
                          aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
                          aws_secret_access_key=access_key_num,
                          region_name='cn-northwest-1'
                          )

    response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        # [start, end) -- excluding end date, follow front closed and back open.
        TimePeriod={
            'Start': time_start,
            'End': time_end
        },
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Metrics=['UnblendedCost']
    )
    cost_total = response['ResultsByTime'][0]['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']

    return account_id, round(float(cost_total), 2)


with open('access_key_cn_new', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        account = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())  # change str to dict
        key_id = account['key_id']
        key_num = account['key_num']
        account_name = account['account_name']

        account_id, cost_total = get_aws_bill_summary(key_id, key_num)
        print("Access ID: %s, Access Name: %s, Cost Total: %s" % (account_id,account_name, cost_total))


Without seeing the detailed data, the difference is probably attributed to either 1) discounts that are not being applied in Cost Explorer or 2) the blended costs are being displayed in Cost Explorer...

Have you checked the data per invoice id? The cost and usage includes all type of costs, i.e. Tax, Discount, RI and so on. They could have difference invoice id and so you should compare them per invoice which may reveal the difference from somewhere.
